# UINavigationController is the wrong size in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

I'm able to add a view from UIView control to cocos2d.  I then resize it using the frame property and it fills up the screen.  Otherwise it looks like it is in portrait view and I can see the cocos2d view behind it and the bottom part is cut off.

So great... everything worked... but then.

I create a UINavigationController.  I try the same thing all over with the uinavigationcontroller.view.frame, but no matter what happens it is stuck in the portrait mode.

How can i resize the view and the UINavigationController stuff so it fills the screen in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

please handle view.frame property like following:

```
        CGRect hrect = viewController.view.frame;
        hrect.size.height = 1500;
        viewController.view.frame = hrect;
```